# Почему select запрос из связанных таблиц не возвращает ничего?

Tags: sql, select

[image: Запрос селект]

[image: Диаграмма]

Не понимаю в чем проблема.....

Comment: а точно должен что-то вернуть? Если хоть 1 запись с таким условием?

Comment: Вопрос с картинкой вместо текста не будет выдаваться поиском, и вероятнее всего, будет закрыт как бесполезный для других участников